# Ubuntu - chmod g+s does not make new files inherit group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod, sticky-bit

I installed a fresh ubuntu with apache2.

I created a new folder "/var/www/foobar" with the following user:group -> `black www-data`.

I need new files created inside this folder to inherit the user and group of that folder.

So I executed `chmod g+s /var/www/foobar`

```
drwxr-xr-t  2 black www-data 4,0K Okt  9 10:12 foobar
```

---

But if I create a new file inside this folder, then the user and group is set to `black black` instead of `black www-data`.

I also tried to add the user to the group `www-data` with `sudo usermod -a -G www-data black` but it made no difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Comment: In your listing above, you are missing an s..  it should be `drwxr-sr-t` so the chmod didn't work.

Comment: There was no error message, it ran through. It just started to work after executing it with sudo.

Comment: Strange there was no error, but the missing bit change shown by ls is a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `chmod g+s <target_path>` with **sudo**, otherwise it wont work.

**Wrong:**

`chmod g+s /var/www/foobar`

**Correct:**

`sudo chmod g+s /var/www/foobar`